# reactjs functional component function/object re-declared (performance concern)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

In the pass I use class components as below:

```
class Car extends React.Component {

    testing = () => {
        console.log(this.props.brand);
    }

    render() {
        testing();
        return <h2>I am a {this.props.brand}!</h2>;
    }
}
```

Nowadays, I need to convert them to functional components as below:

```
function Car(props) {

    const testing = () => {
        console.log(this.props.brand);
    }
     
    testing();

    return (
        <h2>I am a {this.props.brand}!</h2>
    );
}
```

As you can see in the functional component way, the `testing` method is repeating being created during each rendering cycle, and class component way, it is declared outside of render function.

I tried to move it to outside like this:

```
const testing = () => {
    console.log(this.props.brand);
}

function Car(props) {

    testing();

    return (
        <h2>I am a {this.props.brand}!</h2>
    );
}
```

This doesn't work because I need `props` value. I know I can pass `props` in method argument, but I have lot of methods to convert, I do not want to change the method signatures.

I refer to this [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render), it said:

> Are Hooks slow because of creating functions in render? No. In modern
> browsers, the raw performance of closures compared to classes doesn’t
> differ significantly except in extreme scenarios.

That doesn't sound answer the question, it compare the performance of creation of closure and class, which is not the case I am referring to. In my case, it is more referring to the repeating creation of same method in functional components, but not in class components.

Could anyone advise, would that cause any performance issue if I go for functional components?

Comment: You could try `useCallback` or `useMemo` but the overhead of the actual memoization usually ends up being larger than just making the function again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On modern computers, the overhead of creating a function in a block is basically nothing. Like the docs you read say, in extreme scenarios, it *might* be an issue (though unlikely), like maybe if there are 1000 such components and they're being updated multiple times a second - not re-creating the function each render might make the app a tiny bit faster. But this sort of situation is quite unlikely.

Better to strive for code clarity and readability. *If* you find that a particular component is running too slowly, and you've run a performance test to identify the bottleneck(s) in it, go ahead and try to optimize it if you want - but it's probably not worth it before then.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you quoted actually is addressing your exact concern. The answer is no, you don't have to worry about the performance of functional components with enclosed functions compared with class components with methods.

Comment: The document sound like compare "the creation of closure object" to "the creation of class object" for only one time. In reactjs case, it is the render function repeating being called.

Answer (score 0):

Try using useEffect hooks.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function Car(props) {

    const testing = () => {
        console.log(this.props.brand);
    }
     
    useEffect(()=>{
      testing();
    },[])
     
    return (
        <h2>I am a {this.props.brand}!</h2>
    );
}
```

Comment: it is not where `testing();` being called repeatedly, that is fine, it is where `const testing = () =>...` being re-declared is the concern.